# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to define the click event listeners of NavigationButtons by injecting them via Redux's connect. However, those functions are not defined properly, even if they pass the propTypes validation. Sample below:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

import { previousPage, nextPage } from "../actions"

const NavigationButtons = ( onPrevPageClick, onNextPageClick, firstPage = false ) => (
    <div className="navigation-buttons">
        {!firstPage && <div className="previous button" onClick={onPrevPageClick}>Previous Page</div>}
        <div className="next button" onClick={onNextPageClick}>Next page</div>
        <div className="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
);

NavigationButtons.propTypes = {
    onPrevPageClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onNextPageClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ page }) => {
    return {
        firstPage: page == 0
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onPrevPageClick: () => {
            dispatch(previousPage())
        },
        onNextPageClick: () => {
            dispatch(nextPage())
        }
    }
};

const NavigationButtonsContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(NavigationButtons);

export default NavigationButtonsContainer
```

Comment: Can you try logging the `onClick` in `NavigationButtons`?

Comment: I really appreciate the tip (shame on me for not doing so sooner). After doing that the problem became obvious!

Answer (score 0):

The brackets in the function declaration were missing. It should be:

`const NavigationButtons = ({ onPrevPageClick, onNextPageClick, firstPage = false })`

Instead of:

`const NavigationButtons = (onPrevPageClick, onNextPageClick, firstPage = false)`